# Move a Wordpress multisite to subfolder (the whole site)?

Tags: multisite, migration

I'm not talking about subdomain/subfolder. I am talking about moving my whole Wordpress Multisite installation to example.com/ms/. And keeping the root for another non-multisite install of wordpress.
I tried creating a folder /ms/ in the root. Moved everything there. Went to wp-config, changed to define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com/ms');
Then went to phpmyadmin and changed every setting that had example.com to example.com/ms.

Still can't make it work?

How do I do a successful move?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

you can move your multi-site root to ms folder Then

step 1: change the database url into options table for both site and all other url.

```
ex: example.com TO  example.com/ms/
```

step 2: DB **wp_site** table SET your domain name and path:

```
ex: domain :example.com
    PATH: /ms/
```

DB **wp_blogs** table SET your domain name and path for both site:

```
ex: domain :example.com
    PATH: /ms/
    PATH: /ms/your-newtwok-site-name/
```

step 3: **httaces** code and **wp-config** code comments for multi-site. only default code are reaming

step 4: Run your main site it's work after add this line into config.

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

step 5: Login into admin and goto the tools menu. if it's display the message like your plugin disable then disable your plugin and get your new httaces and wp-config code for multi-site after that enable your plugin.

i am done my multi-site move to local to live. hope is work for you.

Note: Please backup your db and files.

Comment: I have done all this, not successful. Dont know what i miss!

Comment: what error give by them? and your main site is working?

Comment: I can make this main site working, but not the network sites, and I cannot login with /wp-admin/ (get an error page).

Comment: OK i will check

Comment: you can change into wp_blogs and wp_site table into database

Answer (score 0):

A recent article on WPMU DEV explained this kind of migration.

As far as I understood from the conversation with Patel, you just miss the second part of Step 4 (single sites db tables).

> **Step 1**
>
> First and foremost, back up your Multisite installation.
>
> **Step 2**
>
> If you haven’t done so already, purchase that fancy new domain name
>   for your network and associate it with the same web hosting account
>   that your Multisite currently lives on.
>
> **Step 3**
>
> You’re going to need to edit the wp-config file in the root directory
>   of your site. You can access this either through your File Manager or
>   FTP. Once you’ve located the file, click on the Edit button to open
>   it. Now, when you configured WordPress for Multisite, you added some
>   code above this line:
>
> ```
> /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
> ```
>
> The line you need want to update in this case is this one:
>
> ```
> define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yournetworkname.com');
> ```
>
> Update “yournetworkname.com” with the new domain name you want to use.
>   You then need to add the following two lines of code above the “That’s
>   all, stop editing!” message:
>
> ```
> define('WP_HOME','https://newnetworkdomain.com');
> define('WP_SITEURL','https://newnetworkdomain.com');
> ```
>
> Save your changes and exit.
>
> **Step 4**
>
> The database files for your Multisite now also need to change to
>   reflect the new domain name of the network. Log into phpMyAdmin. From
>   here, you’re going to need to search for your network’s database
>   tables. Specifically, these are the ones that will require an update
>   from the old domain name to the new one (these are all preceded by
>   “wp_”):
>
> ```
> blogs > domain
> options > home
> options > siteurl
> site
> sitemeta > siteurl
> ```
>
> In addition, you also need to update the following tables for each of
>   the sites that exist on the network. The pound sign (#) below is where
>   you will see the actual site ID number.
>
> ```
> #_options > siteurl
> #_options > home
> #_options > fileupload_url
> ```
>
> Once you have renamed the domain in every instance in which it appears
>   throughout your database tables, you can save your changes and close.
>   Your site should now be fully migrated to the new domain name.
>
> **Step 5**
>
> Don’t forget to change the name of your site as well as the web
>   address within WordPress.
>
> https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/help-i-need-to-migrate-a-wordpress-multisite-a-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: I have followed every step here. I am as far as being able to reach the main page and /wp-admin/, plus I can reach /network/wp-admin/. But all the network site, like one called demo is unreachable from both /ms/demo and /ms/demo/wp-admin/, I get 404 not found. I have edited the URL in this sites database entries.
What am i missing?