# Moved WP Multisite, cannot access sites

Tags: multisite, directory

Just moved my WP Multisite from example.com to example.com/u/
I can access the main site and the admin pages for that and the network admin. But i cannot access the example.com/u/site1 or their example.com/u/site1/wp-admin 
I have changed all the URLs to include the subdirectory, but it still is not working.

What am i missing?

Comment: What options did you change? Please share the details. You should also change the `domain` column in the `wp_blogs` table. Generally, it's a bad idea to move a multisite after it's installed. The process is just sophisticated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296727/move-a-wordpress-multisite-to-subfolder-the-whole-site/296923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was:

```
RewriteBase /u
```

Inside .htaccess